# How to align dropdown-contents to their buttons for different viewport sizes?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I keep changing the position of the dropdown-contents so that they can align with their buttons but I need to make them stick together so on different viewports, I won't have to change their positions and sizes separately.

For example: in ".dropdown-content" class, I have to set different "left"s for different viewports.
But I need the width and position of the dropdown-content to stay same as the width and the position of their parents "menu buttons" so I will only need to change the button width on media queries.

I commented "ATTENTION : start" and "ATTENTION : end" on the areas you need to look at.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Responsive</title>

  </head>

  <header class="header">
       
        <div class="buttons">
         <h1>Web Developer Portfolio</h1>
         <button class="Login">Login</button>
         <button class="signup">Signup</button>
         <button class="btn" onclick="window.location.href='index.html';"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></button>
        </div>
    
      </header>
  
  <body>

  <--! ATTENTION : start --> 

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 col-s-3">
    <div class="pinkContainer">
         <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">About Me</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content" >
            <a href="html.html">Developer News</a>
            <a href="motivation.html">What motivates me</a>
            <a href="#">Examples</a>
            <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
          </div>
         </div>
        
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Portfolio</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Restaurant</a>
            <a href="#">Lawyer's Office</a>
            <a href="#">Design Office</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Tutorials</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="tableofcontent.html">Table of contents</a>
            <a href="#">HTML</a>
            <a href="#">CSS</a>
            <a href="#">JAVASCRIPT</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ATTENTION : end -->

  <div class="col-6 col-s-9">
    <h1>The City</h1>
    <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3 col-s-12">
    <div class="aside">
      <h2>What?</h2>
      <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
      <h2>Where?</h2>
      <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
      <h2>How?</h2>
      <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
}

html {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}

  .header,
  .footer {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(207, 232, 220);
    border: 2px solid rgb(79, 185, 227);
    text-align: center;
  }

  h1 {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    /*text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px black, 4px 4px 3px violet, 2px 2px 1px black, 2px 2px 2px black;*/
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }

  .buttons {

    width: 100%;
    background-color: gold;
    display: inline-block;

  }

  .Login , .signup , .btn {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: salmon;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;

  }

 .aside {
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  }

 /* ATTENTION : start */

.pinkContainer {
  
   background-color: violet;
   padding: 4px;
   border-radius: 15px;

}

  .dropbtn {
    background-color:lightsalmon;
    margin: 3px auto;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;

  }

  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: auto;
    

  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    color: darkgrey;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;

  }

  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn
  {background-color: salmon; border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 5px;}
    

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 
 .dropbtn {
  width: 50%;
}
.dropdown-content {
  width: 40%;
 background-color: lightblue;
}
  
  /* For tablets: */
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 30%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
.dropbtn {
  width: 80%;
}
.dropdown-content {
  width: 80%;
  left: 31px;
}

/* ATTENTION : end */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) then use CSS `position: absolute` to nail the dropdown to it.

The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns a DOMRect object providing information about the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

```
  let rect = my-button.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = window.innerWidth - rect.right;
  my-dropdown.style.top = rect.bottom + "px";
  my-dropdown.style.right = "8px";
```

Comment: I'm not Javascript level yet so I couldn't figure out how to test your code. But I have a hunch that it is what I was looking for.. I'll try to get there soon..